# Lua: compiling C module gives "multiple Lua VMs detected"

Tags: c, lua

I am using Lua 5.3.4 on Mac OS X 10.12 (Sierra).

I have build Lua using "make macosx install".

I am trying to extend Lua, writing a C module that I can call from Lua.
To do that I wrote this C code:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <lua/lua.h>
#include <lua/lauxlib.h>
#include <lua/lualib.h>

static int l_sin (lua_State *L)
{
    double d = lua_tonumber (L, 1);
    lua_pushnumber (L, sin (d));
    return 1;
}

static const struct luaL_Reg mylib[] = {
   {"l_sin", l_sin},
   {NULL, NULL}
};

int luaopen_mylib (lua_State *L)
{
    luaL_newlib (L, mylib);
    return 1;
}
```

If I try to compile it with `gcc -Wall -shared -fPIC -o mylib.so -llua mylib.c` (or in every other way I found online), when I do `l = require "mylib"` on the Lua interpreter, I get `multiple Lua VMs detected`. (of course I have copied the shared library in the right path)

I can't find a solution, can you help me? Thanks

Comment: Found the solution: `gcc -fPIC -dynamiclib -Wl,-undefined,dynamic_lookup -o foo.so foo.c`

Comment: And how is that related to embedded **systems**? Read tag-descriptions before adding.